# C# Reference earlier JSON element - Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm serializing an object which has a `List<X>` and a `Dictionary<X, Y>`.

The `List<X>` is serializing without any issues.
To serialize the dictionary however, I've implemented a custom converter.

```
class XYDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Dictionary<X, Y>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        Dictionary<X, Y> dictionary = new Dictionary<X, Y>();

        foreach (JProperty property in jObject.Properties())
        {
            X key = //Get Y using property.Name

            if (key != null)
            {
                dictionary.Add(key, property.Value.ToObject<Y>());
            }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IDictionary<X, Y> dictionary = (IDictionary<X, Y>)value;

        JObject jObject = new JObject();

        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            jObject.Add(kvp.Key.name, kvp.Value == null ? null : JToken.FromObject(kvp.Value));
        }

        jObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to reference the `List<X>` within the converter. Assuming the JSON is deserialized linearly, the `List<X>` should have been deserialized by this point, but as the `DeserializeObject()` method hasn't finished yet, I don't have any reference to it.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the list within the converter", you mean jObject?

Comment: i think need object type from  property.Value

Comment: @derloopkat The root object being deserialized is received by `DeserializeObject`. Within that class is the List<X> and Dictionary<X, Y>. The problem is that while it is deserializing the dictionary, there is no way for me to access the list.

Comment: By within, I simply meant "during the conversion".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end was to change the way I stored 'X'.
Instead of storing the keys of the dictionary as keys in the json, I stored each keyvaluepair as an array item.

Each item then is: `{ "key": { "$ref" : 5 } "value": { "$ref" : 10 } }`

For writing, this was just a matter of using `JArray`, `JObject`and `JToken.FromObject` (making sure to pass in the serializer.

For reading, `jObject.GetValue("Key").ToObject<X>(serializer)` worked brilliantly.

Hope this helps someone.